# ¿Por que mi documento de Rmarkdown no se ve con el formato correcto en Shiny app?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, markdown, r-markdown

Les dejo aqui un ejemplo reproducible, el problema basicamente es que todo el formato que le di en markdown no se ve reflejado cuando lo cargo desde shiny, entonces en vez de salir el texto en negrita sale **ejemplo** con los asteriscos. A la par aparece otro texto pero este si tiene formato, no logro entender por que si estan escritos de la misma forma.

ui.R

```
    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  hr(),

    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                menuItem("Principal", tabName="principal", icon=icon("pagelines"), selected=TRUE)
                ),width = 285,

    hr())

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "principal",
            withMathJax(), 
            column(width = 8,
                   box(  width = NULL, includeMarkdown("car_iden_adm.Rmd"), collapsible = TRUE,
                         title = "Example", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE))
    )))



dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Title", titleWidth=285),
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$admision_iden_grap <- renderPlotly({})})
```

global.R

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
```

car_iden_adm.Rmd

```
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-6">
**Example:**<br> 
Example
<br>

**Frac:** $\frac{y}{x}$ <br>
<br>

**Type:**<br> 
Principal
<br>
<br>

</div>
<div class = "col-md-6">

**Min:**<br> 95%
<br>
<br>
**Descripcion:** <br>
jlajsdlajdnasjnd
<br>
<br>

</div>
</div>
```

Tengo algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me pasa cuando lo corro con shiny, sin embargo cuando lo corro solo (el boton knit) me sale con el formato correcto.

Comment: Reproduje tu ejemplo y me funcionó lo más bien: http://i.imgur.com/xeN8V52.png, de todas formas a tu código le faltó: `library(plotly)`. Revisa que el código Rmd no tenga un identado ya que eso se interpreta como `code`.-

Comment: Saludos don Patricio, puede por favor reproducir el codigo de nuevo pues le agregue al codigo de rmd unas lineas que al parecer son las que me estan afectando. Cabe resaltar que si lo reprodusco (knit) me sale el formato bien pero si lo hago desde shiny no. @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema es que estás combinando bloques `html` con etiquetas `markdown`, y el  render que usa `shiny` no maneja esta combinación (las etiquetas `<br/>`, si están soportadas en el código markdown). Por lo que podrías hacer dos cosas:

a. Convertir tu código `markdown` a un `HTML` común, e incluirlo luego mediante `includeHTML()`

b. Engañar al render de `markdown` para que considere las etiquetas `html` como texto común.

La opción (a) no necesita demostración, para la (b) vamos a ver en principio como trabaja el `includeMarkdown()`. Esta función termina invocando a `markdown::markdownToHTML()`. Veamos un ejemplo:

```
library("markdown")

# Código markdown puro
html <- markdownToHTML(text="**Hola mundo!**", fragment.only = TRUE)
html
[1] "<p><strong>Hola mundo!</strong></p>\n"

# Código html + markdown
html <- markdownToHTML(text="<div>**Hola mundo!**</div>", fragment.only = TRUE)
html
[1] "<div>**Hola mundo!**</div>\n"
```

Reproducimos tu problema, al incorporar un bloque `html` el render "abandona" el texto a la hora de procesarlo. Podemos engañarlo como dijimos, simplemente reescribiendo los códigos de bloque:

```
html <- markdownToHTML(text="<<div>>**Hola mundo!**<</div>>", fragment.only = TRUE)
html
[1] "<p>&lt;<div>&gt;<strong>Hola mundo!</strong>&lt;</div>&gt;</p>\n"
```

Podemos también reemplazar los `<>` por otro carácter, pero convirtiendolos a esto `<<>>` pareciera funcionar bien, ahora solo resta reconvertir el código:

```
gsub(pattern = '&lt;<', 
     replacement = '<', 
    gsub(pattern = '>&gt;', 
         replacement = '>', 
         x = html
         )
)
[1] "<p><div><strong>Hola mundo!</strong></div></p>\n"
```

Y ahora si combinamos exitosamente ambos códigos.

Finalmente, lo que podrías hacer si eliges esta opción, es:

- Modificar `car_iden_adm.Rmd` reemplazando las etiquetas `html`, por ejemplo `<div>` a `<<div>>`y así con cada una
- Incorporar, por ejemplo en `UI.R` la siguiente función:

  ```
  repair_tags <- function(html) {
      gsub(pattern = '&lt;<', 
           replacement = '<', 
           gsub(pattern = '>&gt;', 
                replacement = '>', 
                x = html
           )
      )
  }
  ```
- Y luego simplemente, hacer: `repair_tags(includeMarkdown("car_iden_adm.Rmd"))`

**Comentario final**: Una duda que tenías es por que `knitr` "dibuja" bien todo y  `shiny` no, la respuesta es que ambos usan distintos workflows, en el caso de `knitr` que apunta a la generación de un documento estático, todo esta construido para usar la herramienta de conversión de formatos: [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/), en el caso de `shiny` que apunta a una generación dinámica (mucho más sencilla) ya vimos que se usa un workflow más simple y la conversión directa desde `rmarkdown::markdownToHTML()`

Comment: Muchas gracias don Patricio por todo el tiempo utilizado para ayudarme, Lamentablemente ninguna de las dos opciones parecen ser aplicables para shiny pues por alguna razón se pierde toda la estructura de las páginas que tengo en la aplicación, es decir en vez de dar clic en un menú para que me despliegue todas las páginas de ese menú lo que hacer es tirarme todas las paginas seguidas hacia abajo sin poder dar clic para desplegar otras. Curiosamente la parte de markdown si se ve bien.

Comment: Pero gracias a su respuesta entendí otra forma de hacerlo y es escribirlo en html directamente en el markdown sin usar el lenguaje que usa markdown y de esta forma si funciona sin desordenar los menús. Nuevamente le agradezco por su ayuda, muy amable. @PatricioMoracho